# NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday, google-api-ruby-client

I am using google_drive gem that depends on google-api-client and the gem versions are:

```
google_drive (1.0.1)
google-api-client (0.7.1)
faraday (0.8.9)
faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
```

Now, on using GoogleDrive:

```
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth('access_token')
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder
from /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@############/gems/google-api-client-0.7.1/lib/google/api_client.rb:118:in `block in initialize'
```

Checked the code for the version of the google-api-client that I am using, here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/google-api-client-0.7.1/lib/google/api_client.rb

Couldn't find anything unusual.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: I am trying it in the console and yes I reloaded the console.